Importing SVG only renders half the image or is missing parts
I have been searching through various sites to try to figure this out but am about to start banging my head against a wall. I have an SVG I am trying to import into Blender, it's a very long path which is why I think I'm having so much trouble. I went through and converted the stroke to a path, and used SVGOMG (which helped a bit) but when I try to import I either get only half the image or random parts of the path are missing.


Left is the SVG in Inkscape, right is in Blender.
Is this an issue with how it's exporting from Inkscape or is it an issue with the fact that there are so many points or something else entirely?
Thanks
